# Pleasse tell me how to resolve application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba

In the following snippet of code:

```
If snpData.State = 1 Then
        Sheets("OptAlert").Select
        CommentDeposit

        ActiveSheet.Range("Table2").Clear
        ActiveSheet.Range("Table2[[Assigned]:[Notes]]").NumberFormat = "[=0]"""";General"
        ActiveSheet.Range("Table2[[Date]]").NumberFormat = "[=0]"""";yyyy-mm-dd"

        **ActiveSheet.Range("Table2[[AVG_HELPER]]").Formula = "=IF(AND([@[AVGOPT]]<pMinAvg,[@[COUNT]]<pOveRid),0,1)"**
        ActiveSheet.Range("Table2[[ALERT_PERCENTAGE]]").Formula = "=IF([@[COUNT]]=0,""" & ChrW(&H221E) & """,ABS([@[AVGOPT]]-[@[COUNT]])/[@[AVGOPT]])"
```

an error occurs in the line marked with the `** ... **`.

Can you help me figure out what is the problem?

Comment: If snpData.State = 1 Then
            Sheets("OptAlert").Select
            CommentDeposit
            
            ActiveSheet.Range("Table2").Clear
            ActiveSheet.Range("Table2[[Assigned]:[Notes]]").NumberFormat = "[=0]"""";General"
            ActiveSheet.Range("Table2[[Date]]").NumberFormat = "[=0]"""";yyyy-mm-dd"
                        
            ActiveSheet.Range("Table2[[AVG_HELPER]]").Formula = "=IF(AND([@[AVGOPT]]<pMinAvg,[@[COUNT]]<pOveRid),0,1)"---------error here

Comment: Please please please... explain what you need...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in trying to evaluate `Range("Table2[[AVG_HELPER]]")` - that may well not be an address that VBA can resolve.

What is `AVG_HELPER` - how is it defined? Can you reference the cell in some other way (do you know the exact address, for example?). If you want to enter the formulat into cell $b$3, for example, you could write

```
[$b$3].Formula = "=IF(AND([@[AVGOPT]]<pMinAvg,[@[COUNT]]<pOveRid),0,1)"
```